# UITextField settext not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is frustrating the hell out of me. I am a beginner programmer and cannot figure out why the text is not being changed.

Here is my method which is supposed to set the text of a UITextField:

```
-(void)updateDays:(NSInteger)days
{
    NSString* daysString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", days];
    [daysTextField setText:daysString];
    [daysString release];
}
```

For whatever reason nothing is happening.

Help appreaciated!

Comment: ...and does `daysTextField`actually reference the UITextField in question?

Comment: do you call 'setNeedsDisplay:YES' on the view holding the TextField?

Answer (score 6):

Anytime you have a frustration along the lines of "why isn't this line working", use the debugger or just add an NSLog before it to print out the relevant data:

```
NSLog(@"updateDays: %@ %@ <= %@", daysTextField, daysTextField.text, daysString);
```

Then you know the line (a) is getting executed, (b) the variables are the ones you think they are, and (c) the values are reasonable.

Comment: +1 you may think you know what your code is doing, but the only way to be sure it to watch it run.  All programmers should do this regularly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this several times, but I think all of them was reasoned by that the `UITextField` was not initialized at that point.

Set a breakpoint and use debugger to **make sure that your `UITextField` is not nil**. You should also check the connection between the .xib file and your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the method is called. If yes check if the textfield is set up properly. Cross check to see if the `IBOutlet` connections are made to the correct object.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too .

It's my code:(in viewdidload)

```
UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)]];
tv.text = @"12345";
tv.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubView:tv];
```

And the text(12345) doesn't show;

Lastly,I found that when i set textColor to gray,or any color not black,it works;

I think that it's a bug of the simulator.

I use xcode 4.2 and the iphone5.0simulator.