# UITextField setText failing to change text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The following method is being called, and the variable days has a valid value. When line 4 prints, the output is "TextField Text: (null). The address for daysTextField is 0x0 (uninstantiated?).

The IBOutlets are hooked up correctly as well as the property/synthesize.

This is really frustrating me.

```
-(void)updateDays:(NSInteger)days
{
    [daysTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", days]];
    NSLog(@"TextField Text: %@", daysTextField.text);
}
```

Help extremely appreciated!

Comment: Try putting something like `NSLog(@"%@", daysTextField)` just to make sure.

Comment: Are you **sure** they're hooked up correctly?  It won't hurt to delete your connections and reconnect them just in case.  It happens all the time, buddy. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField settext not working.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968657/uitextfield-settext-not-working)

Comment: Your frustration is understandable and we empathize, but please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely thing is that `daysTextField` is nil. If this is an IBOutlet from Interface Builder make sure it is connect up correctly. Hope this helps.

You could try this:

```
-(void)updateDays:(NSInteger)days
{
    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", days];
    NSAssert(s, @"string is nil");
    NSAssert(daysTextField, @"daysTextField is nil");
    [daysTextField setText:s];
    NSLog(@"TextField Text: %@", daysTextField.text);
}
```

Your program will crash into the debugger on one or other of the asserts and you will have your answer. The string is very unlikely to be nil.

Comment: I've rehooked them a dozen times expecting a different outcome. Unfortunately no luck yet.

Comment: Then you may be calling `updateDays` before `viewDidLoad`. Also if you knew `daysTextField` was `nil` it would have been good to mention this in your question.